# Books and Tutorials for OpenGL ES on Android and Object Oriented Programming

Tags: android, oop, opengl-es-2.0

Currentlt I'm finding some books to improve my knowledge on OpenGL ES and Object Oriented Programming as I would need them sooner or later. Can someone recommend some books or sites that provide good understanding on OpenGL ES and OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solid understanding of how OpenGL ES 2.0 works I would suggest [OpenGL® ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com/). The book does not try to (nor promises to) turn you into a OpenGL guru, it rather just teaches you the fundamentals.
Note that there is a substantial difference between OpenGL ES 2.0 and OpenGL ES (for instance OpenGL ES 2.0 is not backwards compatible).

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).